# Executing a JavaScript with an event that will only occur when any other event occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom-events

I tried to check a HTML DOM Events' document to see if there's a HTML DOM Event that will only occur when any other event without a specific event occurs, but I found nothing..

Is there a HTML DOM Event that will only occur when any other event occurs?

If no, is it possible to create a JavaScript that will only execute if any event occurs?
*(I mean, no specific event, it will always execute if any event occurs.)*

If it's possible, could you please show me an idea how to create it?

Comment: You mean any event at all, or only those events to which a handler has been bound somewhere? If you want to include events even without handlers, it's going to be constantly firing your omni-handler as the mouse moves around the page. I don't know how you'd make sense of anything if you did that.

Comment: ...what are you ultimately trying to accomplish? And what does this have to do with AJAX?

Comment: @cookiemonster Okay, I have a JS that will change the *.innerHTML* of all the tags with my specific class if the page is in a ready state.. And I also want to change the inner of any new tag with my specific class, that's created by another JS which I do not control..

Comment: I don't see what this can't be done. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: I don't understand what that has to do with tracking all events. It sort of sounds like you want to have some code run when elements have been added to the DOM. Is that right? It's a little hard to tell from your description.

Comment: @jamesemanon I think I have a temporary solution.. Visit http://professionalserver.tk/php/textimage/ and edit their *Elements* and add this tag `<div class="imageText">ANY TEXT</div>` to see what I mean..

Comment: @cookiemonster Please take a look at my previous comment..

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to react to changes in the DOM, that are not made by your script.

You should look into the [MutationObserver-API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) if you are not trying to support old browsers. Taking the example there as a starting point, you could try something like this:

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('body');

function mutationCallback(mutation) {
  /*
    Your logic here
  */
}

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(mutationCallback);    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I found a good Article on Events in the DOM in general, also discussing Mutation-Events: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't an event that triggers when any event occurs: it would probably not have a use other than crashing your browser. If you're trying to see if the user is away from his keyboard, then there are a lot of other methods, as asking him so, and seeing if he responds in a certain range of time. If you don't want him to notice that you're doing an afk test, then use the mousemove event listener on the body element